# Covariant vs partial derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, general-relativity

Heads up: this is a duplicate from physics S.E. where it is being treated as off topic. I hope its not a problem that I repost here ?

**Question**

$\partial_\mu \vec{V} = 0$, does this imply that $\nabla_\mu V^\kappa = 0$ ?

**My argument**

For any vector $\vec{V}$ we can write that $V=V^\kappa \vec{g_\kappa}$ with $\vec{g_\kappa} = \partial \vec{r}/\partial r^\kappa$ such that:

$$0= \partial_\mu \vec{V} = \partial_\mu(V^\kappa \vec{g}_\kappa) = \partial_\mu (V^\kappa) \vec{g_\kappa} + V^\kappa \partial_\mu(\vec{g_\kappa}) = \partial_\mu (V^\kappa) \vec{g_\kappa} + V^\kappa \Gamma_{\mu\kappa}^\rho \vec{g_\rho} = \partial_\mu (V^\kappa) \vec{g_\kappa} + V^\rho \Gamma_{\mu\rho}^\kappa \vec{g_\kappa} = \nabla_\mu (V^\kappa) \vec{g_\kappa}$$

projecting onto the different basis vectors than gives the result that $\nabla_\mu V^\kappa = 0$

**Additional question**

If this is true, and we consider a translation in space $\vec{x} \rightarrow \vec{x} + \vec{a}$ with $\vec{a}$ constant. Do we than find that $\nabla_\mu a_\nu = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite, and for two reasons:

1) The quantity $\partial_\mu V $ is not well-defined for $V$ a *vector*, that is, it transforms in a non-tensorial way under a change of coordinates. 
Since $\partial _\mu V= (\partial _\mu V^\nu) \partial _\nu$ it is enough to check that $\partial_\mu V^\nu$ does not transform tensorially. To see this consider the following example. Let $V$ be the vector field in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $V=\partial _x$ where $(x,y)$ are the usual Cartesian coordinates. With respect to the coordinate basis $\{\partial_x,\partial_y\}$ we have $V^x=1,V^y=0$ hence all the terms $\partial_\mu V^\nu$, $\mu,\nu\in\{x,y\}$ vanish. Consider however the same vector field in polar coordinates,
\begin{equation}
\partial_x=  \cos\theta\  \partial_r -(\sin\theta/r)\ \partial_\theta.
\end{equation}
With respect to the coordinate basis $\{\partial_r,\partial_\theta\}$ e.g. $\partial_\theta V^r=-\sin\theta \neq 0$ hence it cannot hold $\partial_\theta V^r = J_\theta ^\mu J^r _\nu\partial _\mu V^\nu$, where $J^\mu_\theta =\partial_\theta V^\mu$, $J^r_\nu = \partial_\nu V^r$, $\mu,\nu\in\{x,y\}$ are (entries of) the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation and its inverse. 
You can still define and use $\partial_\mu V$ in  a fixed coordinate system but that is  not very useful.
In fact this is the reason for introducing the covariant derivative.

Instead, the partial derivative of a *function* transforms tensorially as we have, by the chain rule (or the transformation law for 1-forms if you prefer) 
\begin{equation*}
\partial_a f = J^\mu_a \partial_\mu f,
\end{equation*}
so if it vanishes in a coordinate system it vanishes in all. If it is non-zero it transforms in a controlled way, namely by the Jacobian of the change of bases. This is why we want to work with quantities which transform tensorially.

2) The covariant derivative of a vector field is well-defined, that is independent of the coordinate system. Applied to a function (as opposed to a tensor) however, it is simply the ordinary partial derivative, so
\begin{equation*}
\nabla_\mu V^\nu=\partial_\mu V^\nu \neq \nabla_\mu V=\nabla_\mu (V ^\nu \partial_\nu)
=(\partial_\mu V^\nu)\partial_\nu +V^\nu \nabla_\mu \partial_\nu 
=\Big( \partial_\mu V^\rho + V^\nu \Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}\Big) \partial_\rho
\end{equation*}
In fact, the extra term in the covariant derivative
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}=  \mathrm{d}x^\rho \Big(\nabla_\mu (\partial_\nu)\Big)
\end{equation}
is the correction required to obtain an expression which transforms in a tensorial way under changes of coordinates.

Comment: I don't underststand why you would say that: $V^\mu \partial_\mu \rightarrow V^\mu J_\mu^\rho \partial_\rho$. I thought that the compontens of a vector would transform as well if we go to a different basis and that these two transformattions cancel ?

Even shorter: how can $V^\nu \partial_\nu$ not transfrom to $V^a \partial_a$ since that would violate it being a vector wouldn't it ?

ps: my source onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9783527618132.app6/pdf

Comment: You are right, my proof of the fact that $\partial _\mu V$ is not tensorial is wrong, the fact itself is true though, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for you effort but I still fail to understand your argument. You say that $\partial_\mu (V^\rho \partial_\rho) = \partial_\mu(V^\rho) \partial_\rho$ I agree that this is true in carthesian coordinates. But if we work in e.g. polar coordiantes than $\partial_\theta(\partial_\theta) = \partial_\theta(\vec{e_\theta}) = -\vec{e_r}$ isn't it ?

Comment: If $\partial_\mu V \mathrm{d}x^\mu$ were a tensor its components with respect to different bases would be related by the appropriate Jacobians. With respect to the Euclidean coordinate basis $\{\partial_\mu\}$ the components are $\partial_\mu V^\nu = 0$. If it were a tensor, its component with respect to the polar coordinates coordinate basis $\{\partial_a\}=\{\partial_r,\partial_\theta\}$ should be $\partial_a V^b= J^\mu_a J^b_\nu \partial_\mu V^\nu =0$  but they are not. Hence it is not a tensor.

Comment: But I argued that the components of $\partial_\mu (V^\rho \partial_\rho) = \nabla_\mu (V^\rho) \partial_\rho$ which is a tensor isn't it ?

Comment: You haven't argued. You simply set $\partial_\mu g_k = \nabla_\mu g_k$, which is unjustified, at which point of course you recover the covariant derivative.

Comment: I think I get the point. This definition of the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu} = \vec{g}^\rho \partial_\mu \vec{g}_\nu$ takes parrallel transport into account since it ignores the contributions of the new vector field that are orthogonal to the tangent space ?
Is this correct ?

Comment: There is no  canonical way to define the partial derivative of a vector field (e.g. $g_k$) because you need to identify tangent spaces at different points. Parallel transport is a way to do that but depends on extra structure - but if you are using parallel transport you are really taking a covariant derivative, in which case it would be better to use the standard notation. This is probably the same as what you are saying.

Comment: Yes I get it now.
Thanks again for all your effort !